# How to pass access token from API Manager to ESB endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

It's possible to pass access token from AM to ESB endpoint? (once AM has validated this access token by header Authorization: Bearer). If I try to parse the transport property of Authorization, in ESB, it has null value. Does AM take out this header before passing the message to ESB endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default it takes out authorization headers. You can keep the oauth headers without removing by, making RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage false in api-manager.xml. It is commented out by default. So uncomment that and make as false.

```
<RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage>false</RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage>
```